# Attach csv file to mail in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, csv, python-2.7, email-attachments

How can I attach a csv file I create myself?

I can create a csv file with

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage()
email.attach(filename = 'a.csv', mimetype = 'text/csv', content = 'my content')
```

but I have to write several lines.

I've tried many Things with

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['first cell'])
```

but I can't mix these things

I can attach a csv file to a mail with

```
email = EmailMessage()
email.encoding = 'utf-8'
email.subject = Subject'
email.body = ''
email.to = ['my_mail@gmail.com',]

myfile = open('test.csv', 'w+')
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
wr.writerow(['test'])

email.attach(filename = 'a.csv', mimetype = 'text/csv', content = myfile.read())
email.send()
```

but the content in the file is corrupt, and it seems weird to set a file name multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringIO.StringIO()` instance to create an in-memory file-like object, which you can write to as a CSV and then attach the contents to your email.